# How to edit and watermark animated gifs, preferably through php?

Tags: php, gif, animated-gif

Ive been looking everywhere for something that could manipulate animated gif files, server-side, preferably through php, but simple command line tools that could be executed via exec() would do also. Essentially Im looking to watermark animated gif files, as well as have the ability to cull frames out of animations (every 2nd, 3rd frame to be removed for example).

Anything like that out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

See animated GIF example here: http://valokuva.org/?p=46

Comment: Please update  your answer as it is appearing in top of search results and example site is down.

Comment: @RavinderPayal: made it community wiki, feel free to update