# How to apply a watermark to an uploaded picture using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, watermark

How can I apply a watermark to an uploaded picture using PHP?

Example LINK: http://www.kitebeaches.com/kitesurf/uploadPicture/NIRVANA_Club_Village.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (adapted from [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/watermark-images-php/)):

```
<?php  

header('content-type: image/jpeg');  
$yourimagefile = 'something.jpg' // the image you're wanting to watermark
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');  // the watermark
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);  
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($yourimagefile);  
$size = getimagesize($yourimagefile);  
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;  
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;  
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);  
imagejpeg($image);  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend WideImage for this sort of thing: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/tutorials/watermarkmerge/

Answer (score 5):

Previously on SO:

- [How can I add an image onto an image
  in PHP like a watermark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217820/how-can-i-add-an-image-onto-an-image-in-php-like-a-watermark)
- [Can this watermark function be
  improve (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282873/can-this-watermark-function-be-improve-php)
- [How to watermark GIF image with
  24-bit PNG with transparency in
  PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216433/how-to-watermark-gif-image-with-24-bit-png-with-transparency-in-php)
- [How to edit and watermark animated
  gifs, preferably through php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743267/how-to-edit-and-watermark-animated-gifs-preferably-through-php)

Comment: I love you, even if you could have given him more link form SO ^^

Comment: And now: ***the saga continues***! (Incidentally, +1 for the tv-show homage and the research to make your point.)