# Auto Watermark Adder to Image in Server

Tags: php, html, css

I have my site vestock.tk
I am a photographer and planning to upload my photos on my website.
But I wanted a code which would automatically paste a photo on that image which I upload on server.

I tried GOOGLE but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a transparent bg image which I want.
Plz tell me the right way to do.

Thanks

Harsh Bansal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a watermark to an uploaded picture using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420933/how-to-apply-a-watermark-to-an-uploaded-picture-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('water_mark.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('your_image.jpg');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Comment: Can u tell me how to use those numbers